# What does this HTML and JS do?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1>Change an HTML element</h1>
<p id="msg">Now you see me.</p>
<button type="button"
onclick="document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = 'Gone!'">
Click Me!</button>
<button type="button"
onclick="document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = 'Back again!'">
Bring me back!</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Can someone explain what this does?

Comment: With all due respect, This is so googleable that you should be ashamed

Comment: Your code : https://jsfiddle.net/L8Lushqx/

Comment: yo thx ove never seen this type of website! its awesome now i can do it :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When you click on the first button it fires an onclick event attribute. You've told the event to find an element by the ID of 'msg'. Which is the `<p>` tag above.

It finds it and then replaces the innerHTML value of "Now you see me" with the string 'Gone!'. Pretty much the same thing happens with the second button.

You can learn more about it at the web address below.
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onclick.asp